# How to construct a $p$-adic power series $g(x)$ over $O$ or over $\text{Frac}(O)$ from a given series $f(x) $?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $K \supseteq \mathbb{Q}_p$ be the $p$-adic field with ring of integer $O$ and maximal ideal $M$. Let $\bar M$ be the closure of $M$.

Let $f(x)$ be a noninvertible power series in $ x \cdot O[[x]]$ having `only simple roots`.

Consider an infinite subset $S \subset \bar M$ such that $f(\alpha)$ takes values in $S$ for all $\alpha \in S$.

I want to construct a power series $g(x) \in x \cdot O[[x]]$ or over $\text{Frac}(O)$ which interpolate $f(x)$ on $S$ and has at least `one multiple root` that is:

(i) $g(\alpha)=f(\alpha)$ $\forall \alpha \in S$,

(ii) $g(x)$ has at least one root with multiplicity $\geq 2$.

---

The [note](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/math5020f11/padicinterpolation.pdf) on $p$-adic interploation says a function $f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{Q}_p$ extend to a continuous function $\mathbb{Z}_p \to \mathbb{Q}_p$. I am not sure whether this extends to a finite extension $K/\mathbb{Q}_p$.

Any comment here, please.

But I am thinking the following `possible` way:

Let $g(x)=x^m \circ f(x)=(f(x))^m$ for $m \geq 2$.

Then clearly $g(x)$ has multiple roots.

To conclude this infinite case, we have to show $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S$ i.e., we have to show $$f(\alpha)=(f(\alpha))^m.$$

Assume $f(\alpha)$ is idempotent for all $\alpha \in S$  (which is not always true though). In that case $f(\alpha)=(f(\alpha))^2$ implies $f(\alpha)=(f(\alpha))^m$ for $m \geq 2$.

I have doubt the approach is correct.

Can you please suggest me any authentic way to anwer my question ?

Thanks

Comment: If $S$ has a  convergent sequence $s_n\to s$ then $f$ is fully determined by the $f(s_n)$. Proof: look at the derivatives of $f(s+x)$ at $0$.

Comment: @reuns, Can you expand the comment in an answer ? How does this help to construct $g(x)$ from $f(x)$ ? If you can answer case-II, please

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do. What is $f$. In general it is not obvious to find if there exists a polynomial taking some given values on $O/p^nO$, there are plenty of congruence constraints. $f(\alpha)=(f(\alpha))^m$ doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @reuns, ok. Here $f(x) \in x \cdot O[[x]]$ is a power series and $f(x)$ has simple zeros over $\bar{M}$. I want to construct another power series $g(x)$ so that they agree on $S$ i.e., $f(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S$ but unlike $f(x)$, now $g(x)$ will have `at least one multiple root`. This is what I want. Any guide please

Comment: @reuns, as mentioned, $O$ is the ring of integers of the $p$-adic field $K$, $f$ is a noninvertible p-adic power series over $O$ without constant term, and with simple roots in $\bar M$ and $S$ is an infinite subset of the closure $\bar M$ of the maximal ideal $M$. We know that a noninvertible power series can have finitely many roots in $M$ and in $O$. Now I need to construct $g$ to solve a problem in $p$-adic power series as mentioned above. Well, in my question, $S$ is set of roots of all iterates $f^{\circ n}(x)$ in $\bar M$ and thus an infinite subset of $\bar M$.

Comment: Your level of "generality" doesn't make sense because it is clear you are not seeing the huge amount of congruences constraints making your $g$ non-existent in many cases. Again what is your $f,S$ and what do you want to do with $g$.

Comment: @reuns, well. Take for example, $u(x)=\pi x+x^q$ with $q=|O/\pi O|$ and $S=\{x \in \bar M: u^{\circ n}(x)=0\}$. Consider the Galois group $G=\text{Gal}(\bar K/K)$ and let $h(x) \in G$ and   suppose we have the relation $h(\alpha)=f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S$, for some noninvertible power series $f(x) \in x \cdot O[[x]]$ and where $f(x)$ has simple roots. Thats all. Now I want another power series $g \in x \cdot O[[x]]$ which has `at least one multiple root` so that $h(\alpha)=g(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S$. This is original question.

Comment: @reuns, that is  I want to replace $f$ in the relation $h(\alpha)=f(\alpha)$ by a power series $g$ which has multiple roots. This is what I want. How to get it, under which assumption ?

Comment: $h(\alpha)$ has the same valuation as $\alpha$ so it can't be $=f(\alpha)$. I don't know how to "see" the set $S$. Is it complicated? Why do you care of multiple root?

Comment: @reuns, The first sentence of your comment is not clear to me. How $v(h(\alpha))=v(\alpha)$ ? Also even if this happen, we still can have $v(f(\alpha))=v(\alpha)$ because $x \neq y$ may imply $v_p(x)=v_p(y)$. Here the set $S$ is set of zeros of all iterates of $u$. Note that $h(\alpha) \in  S$ as Galois element permutes the roots. Also $u \circ f=f \circ u$ and hence $f(\alpha) \in S$ as well. That is, both $h$ and $f$ takes values in the set  $S$. We have assumed that $h(\alpha)=f(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha \in S$, which is quite possible, where $f$ has simple roots only.

Comment: @reuns, you mentioned that $h(\alpha)$ has same valuation as $\alpha$. It is not clear to me. Because $\alpha \in S \subseteq \bar M$, and so `not all` $\alpha \in S$ belongs to $K$ only but also in $\bar K$ and hence $h(\alpha) \neq \alpha$ `for some` $\alpha \in S$. So $v(h(\alpha))$ may not have same valuation as $\alpha$. So can you please explain what are you meaning here actually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\in p^{-N}O[[x]]$ (well-defined as a function $p^\epsilon O_{\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p}\to O_{\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p}$) then for any $r>0$, $f$ has finitely many roots of valuation $\ge r$.

If $S$ contains infinitely many elements of valuation $\ge r$ and $f|_S=g|_S$ for another $g\in p^{-N}O[[x]]$ then $f=g$.

The case $S$ finite is already treated by Merosity.

Comment: Your answer is helpful. But I don't have the proof of the facts you mentioned. Why $f \in p^{-N}O[[x]]$ has finitely many roots of valuation $\geq r$ ? Can you please explain it ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach that will work in the finite case, but not sure if/when it will work in the infinite case, since it depends on what $S$ looks like. Since we know $g(\alpha)-f(\alpha)=0$ we can define it as,

$$g(x) - f(x) = xh(x)\prod_{\alpha \in S} (1-\frac{x}{\alpha})$$

Since we want $g$ to not have a constant term, the $x$ was placed on the product. Furthermore since we want $g$ to have a double root, we'll specify $h$ with two free variables which we can use to solve for a condition on a root. We'll put the root at $x=r$, which must lie in the region of convergence of $f$.

$$h(x)=a+b(x-r)$$

This specifically gives us $h(r)=a$ and $h'(r)=b$ which will give us a system of equations to solve for $g(r)=g'(r)=0$.

Specifically,

$$a = -\frac{f(r)}{r}\prod_{\alpha \in S} (1-\frac{r}{\alpha})^{-1}$$

$$b = \frac{f'(r)}{f(r)} - 1 + \sum_{\alpha \in S} \frac{1}{\alpha-r}$$

Comment: It looks fine to me. I think this will probably work when $S$ is infinite if we can show the infinite product $\prod_{S}(1-x/\alpha)$ as well as the infinite sum in the last equation converges. Note that in infinite case, $S$ can be think of as a `set of roots` in $\bar M$ of `all iterates of a power series` in $x \cdot O[[x]]$.

Comment: No, you are missing the congruences making your functions not in $O[[x]]$. @Masmath

Comment: @reuns, can you please elaborate it as an answer explaining how the congruences making problem here ? Because $f(x) \in x \cdot O[[x]]$ already given. But I don't understand how `just attaching` one double root to $f(x)$ is making the new function $g(x)$ not in $O[[x]]$ ? What are the difficulties and when it is possible ? I really can't understand/see the congruences that you are talking about. Suppose if the new function $g(x)$ not in $O[[x]]$, could I consider it on $\text{Frac}(O)[[x]]$ or $K[[x]]$ ? Please elaborate it showing all difficulties and when it is possible

Comment: The elements $\alpha$ in the denominator aren't going to work out.

Comment: @Merosity, So we can consider $g(x)$ is a power series over the fraction field $\text{Frac}(O)$ of the integer ring $O$. Isn't it ?